# Using @ExceptionHandler to serve JSON or HTML response based on @RequestMapping

Tags: java, spring-mvc

My controller has methods that produce JSON or HTML depending on their @RequestMapping(produces="", consumes="") annotations. However when it comes to handling exceptions in a generic way, I am facing problems.

```java
@RequestMapping(method = POST)
public String add(@Valid MyForm form, BindingResult result, Model model) {
    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        return "edit";
    }

    throw new RuntimeException("Error adding");

    return "edit";
}

@RequestMapping(method = POST, produces = "application/json", consumes = "application/json")
@ResponseBody
public Map<String, Object> addJSON(@RequestBody @Valid MyForm form, Model model) {
    throw new RuntimeException("Error adding");
}
```

How do I write @ExceptionHandler for the above two methods? The one for the non-JSON one should add an attribute to the `Model`.

```
model.addAttribute("error", exception.getMessage());
```

The one with JSON response type should return the error as a `Map`, to be later serialized into JSON.

I tried the below but spring doesn't like two different @ExceptionHandler annotated methods declared with the same exception type.

```java
@ExceptionHandler(RuntimeException.class)
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
@RequestMapping(produces = "application/json")
@ResponseBody
public Map<String, Object> handleExceptionAsJSON(RuntimeException exception) {
    Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("error", exception.getMessage());

    return map;
}

@ExceptionHandler(RuntimeException.class)
public Map<String, Object> handleException(RuntimeException exception) {
    Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("error", exception.getMessage());

    return map;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Both of your `ExceptionHandler` have `RuntimeException` argument. Therefore, in your case only 1 `exceptionhandler` is honored.

I'm not sure what you're up to. But I guess writing your own `exceptionresolver` would solve your problem. I already did this. I created my own `exceptionresolver` that is dedicated for Ajax requests only and then chained it with the existing `ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver`.

Comment: "ExceptionHandler is mapped against the throwable argument. Therefore, in your case only 1 exceptionhandler is honored." - that is not true!

Comment: I modified my first line above. If you don't believe me, please check **line 71** (detectExceptionMappings method) of `ExceptionHandlerMethodResolver`. Spring 3.2.x is my reference by the way.